# Reverting merge using mainline parent-number

Tags: git

What is --mainline parent-number in git revert?
When I revert merging, with log(before merging), I though it would revert f1 branch, but it was reverting f1 and f2 both.

```
commit f932068caca9b25fc5b68b25b907a7fb39250510 (HEAD -> master)
Merge: 2a5ca98 4e171d0 6bdcc66

    Merge branches 'f1', 'f2' and 'f3'

commit 6bdcc66e5556250ae1174257fbdf426aba0bfc2b (f3)

    f3 file added

commit 4e171d0e9cf81c092879418e17ba5d515c7dc332 (f2)

    1st commit in f2

commit 2a5ca9806fc0922a013d2e1484c19ac3ea0a23b3 (f1)

    1st commint in f1

commit 0a9eee7e8d1750d6a2ae2b93347144f3a42ae70d

1st commit in master
```

after revert, I am getting as below,

```
$ git revert f932068 -m 3
[master 23b0313] Revert "Merge branches 'f1', 'f2' and 'f3'"
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 f1file
 delete mode 100644 f2file
```

why its reverting both f1 and f2 branches merge? and here -m 3 means what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your commit `Merge branches 'f1', 'f2' and 'f3'` is a *(very uncommon!)* octo-merge, i.e. you merged multiple branches into `master` with a single commit. While git is capable of doing that, you essentially loose the ability to revert any part in it.

Then: `git revert` does not remove commits, it simply creates an additional commit which *undoes* the changes introduced by some other change. By default (has `git help revert` helpfully points out), `revert` is not capable of reverting a merge commit, because it does not know which of the originating (typically 2, but 4 in your case) source commits you consider your "before" state you want to revert *to*.

In your case, specifying `-m 3` designates merge parent no. 3 (i.e. branch `f3`) as the "mainline" you want to revert to:

```
Merge: 2a5ca98 4e171d0 6bdcc66
       ^       ^       ^
Parent 1       2       3
```

That way, your command instructs git to revert changes introduced by parents 1 & 2, but not parent 3, keeping your changes from `f3` intact.